# Constructing a OLAP Cube in Snowflake

Tags: olap, cube, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to reconstruct a Cognos Transformer cube in Snowflake. 
1. Do we have an option to build an OLAP cube in Snowflake (like SSAS, Cognos Transformer)? 
2. Any recommendations of what the approach should be or steps to be followed?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no option similar to an SSAS cube in Snowflake. Once data is loaded into the databases Snowflake allows to query the data in a way similar to traditional OLTP databases.

For data aggregations the Snowflake library offers rich sets of in-built functions. Together with UDFs, SPs and Materialized Views we can build custom solutions for precomputed data aggregations.

For data analysis we still have to rely upon third party tools. Snowflake provides a variety of different connectors to access its database objects from other analytical tools.
There are plans in near future to introduce an integrated tool for data aggregations, analysis and reporting.

Answer (score 1):

Use TM1 to build your OLAP cube, then run Cognos over the top of the TM1 cube. 
TM1 will have no problem shaping your Snowflake data into OLAP structure.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake is no multidimensional database and offers analytical statements like "Group by cube" as Oracle also does. But this is more like a matrix with aggregations. There's no drill down or drill up available like SSAS Cubes, PowerCubes and other multidimensional databases (MDDB) are offering.

An option could be to simulate OLAP by creating ad hoc aggregations and use JavaScript to drill down / drill up. But in my experience operations equal to drilling will take often more than 10 seconds (if not extremly high ressources are available). Snowflake is probably not the best solution for such use cases.